# Object Formatting: Graphics as In-line Symbols

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, inline

I'm trying to create an in-line symbol that is a specific shape. I'm wondering how I can have something like this in my document:

[image]

Comment: I'd need them to be colored too...

Comment: Can you get spell check in LaTeX?

Comment: Since you're looking for different shapes, supply a list, or something that describes the object generically. As it stands now, this question is too broad.

Comment: The "general shape" would be every combination of fill-able cells for the 2-grid, namely the thing that looks like this: $\boxplus$

Comment: I understand. There's no MathJax formatting on this site. You tagged the question with [tag:tikz-pgf]; is this your preferred solution? What have you tried thus far?

Comment: I am currently using this: ${\color{green}\overset{\text{\Large$\square\square$}}{\text{$\hspace{0.4cm}$\Large$\square$}}}$

Comment: Which do you think is better? @Werner

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\def\block#1{\color{#1}\rule{1ex}{1ex}}
\begin{document}
\parbox{3in}{%
\ldots here we can see that since the bla bla bla conjecture asserts that 
{\def\stackalignment{r}\stackon[0pt]{\block{blue}}{\block{green}\block{magenta}}} 
is different from
{\block{blue}}
\ldots
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I get the following error: `! LaTeX Error: File `stackengine.sty' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)

Enter file name: `

Comment: @LoieBenedicte It's a relatively new package.  It can be found at http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/stackengine.  Putting the sty file in your current directory will allow the code to compile.  In the longer term, you should find the directory where LaTeX would like it installed.

Comment: readarray.sty? What about that?

Comment: @LoieBenedicte  Likewise in http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/readarray

Comment: Hmm... How can you make the blocks bigger?

Comment: @LoieBenedicte The definition of `\block` specifies a 1ex x 1ex square, where 1ex is the height of a lower-case x.  You could make it 1.3ex, for example, in that definition.  If you make it too big, it could affect interline spacing.

Comment: Where is the definition?

Comment: The 4th line of code: `\def\block#1{\color{#1}\rule{1ex}{1ex}}`

Answer (score 2):

You can define a set of block-commands that defines a hierarchy:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xcolor
\newcommand{\oneblock}[2][1ex]{{\color{#2}\rule{#1}{#1}}}
\newcommand{\twoblock}[3][1ex]{\oneblock[#1]{#2}\oneblock[#1]{#3}}
\newcommand{\fourblock}[5][1ex]{\leavevmode\rlap{%
  \raisebox{#1}{\twoblock[#1]{#2}{#3}}}% Upper \twoblock
  \twoblock[#1]{#4}{#5}}% Lower \twoblock
\begin{document}
Here we can see that since the bla bla bla conjecture asserts that 
\fourblock{green}{magenta}{white}{blue} is different from \oneblock{blue} and 
\twoblock{green}{magenta!50} or even \twoblock[1.5ex]{red!80!black}{orange!70}.
\end{document}
```

- `\oneblock[<wd>]{<col1>}` prints one block of width `<wd>` and colour `<col1>`;
- `\twoblock[<wd>]{<col1>}{<col2>}` prints `\oneblock[<wd>]{<col1>}\oneblock[<wd>]{<col2>}`;
- `\fourblock[<wd>]{<col1>}{<col2>}{<col3>}{<col4>}` prints a raised `\twoblock[<wd>]{<col1>}{<col2>}` on top of `\twoblock[<wd>]{<col3>}{<col4>}`.

The default width is `1ex`, which can be changed via the first optional argument.

Of course, enhancements are possible, and even the interface can be changed, if needed.